# Is there a way to create a button with corner radius, gradient, and with dynamic shadows?

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a button with corner radius and gradient, but I also want its shadows to react on user press and release. I'm trying out a Container with decoration but no luck since I can't seem to find an onRelease callback. So I'm thinking that I'm on the wrong direction. So is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you share some code that you have been working on so we can help point you in the right direction?

Comment: thanks but I already solved it, my code is in the first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This button has exactly what I need:
A gradient, rounded corners, dynamic shadows, ripple effect`Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                                child: Transform.scale(
                                  scale: btnScale,
                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                    onTapCancel: () {
                                      setState(() {});
                                      btnHeight = 5;
                                      btnScale = 1.0;
                                    },
                                    onTapDown: (loc) {
                                      btnHeight = 0;
                                      btnScale = 0.99;
                                      setState(() {});
                                    },
                                    onTapUp: (loc) {
                                      setState(() {});
                                      btnHeight = 5;
                                      btnScale = 1.0;
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 190,
                                      height: 62,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            new BoxShadow(
                                              blurRadius: 4,
                                              color: Colors.black12,
                                              offset: new Offset(
                                                  -btnHeight, btnHeight),
                                            ),
                                            new BoxShadow(
                                              blurRadius: 4,
                                              color: Colors.black12,
                                              offset: new Offset(
                                                  btnHeight, btnHeight),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(100)),
                                          gradient: BtnTeal),
                                      child: Material(
                                        color: Colors.transparent,
                                        child: InkWell(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              (BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                          onTap: () {},
                                          highlightColor:
                                              const Color(0xFF63DCA0),
                                          splashColor: Colors.teal,
                                          child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              "LOG IN",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 21,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),`